# Does a locally volume-preserving deformation also preserves volume globally?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, continuum-mechanics, volume

Is a locally volume-preserving deformation (in which the determinant of the deformation gradient (a.k.a Jacobian) is unity) is also globally volume preserving?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: @ChetMiller
I just came up with this equality: $V_\mathrm{deformed}=\int\mathrm{d}V_\mathrm{deformed}=\int J \mathrm{d}V_0=\int\mathrm{d}V_0=V_0$, so its seems that the volume is also globally preserved; what do you think? Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: What if J is a function of spatial position?

Comment: @ChetMiller Then the assumption of local volume preservation is violated, because it holds only when $J=1$ at any point.

Comment: I don't follow that at all.

Comment: @ChetMiller I did not get you; If you do not follow the local volume preservation assumption, then you are not discussing the PO.